# É possivel fazer uma chamada sincrona ao WebApi?

Tags: c#, xamarin, asp.net-web-api

- É possível fazer chamadas não assíncronas ao `WebApi`?
- Eu não quero que minha aplicação passe batido pelo método que executa a consulta ao `WebApi`, eu quero que ela espere uma resposta e tome uma atitude conforme o retorno, mas todos os exemplos que vi de chamadas a `WebApi` são `Async`.
  O que eu devo fazer?
- Minha arquitetura é que está errada?

nesse exemplo eu gostaria de carregar o grid

```
    private void btnListaGenerica_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task<List<Empresa>> ListEmpresa = this.GetAll<Empresa>(); 

        dgvDados.DataSource = ListEmpresa; 
    }

    private async Task<List<T>> GetAll<T>()
    {
        try
        { 
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:49783/api/empresas/listall"))
               if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        //clienteUri = response.Headers.Location;
                        var ProdutoJsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T[]>(ProdutoJsonString).ToList();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         return null;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Impossível responder essa pergunta sem saber qual há linguagem que vai consumir a API.

Comment: Você utiliza a API da forma que for mais conveniente. Que tipo de exemplo você viu? aplicações WEB front-end?

Comment: Eu estou usando C# em .net WebApi e um app em xamarin com c# também

Comment: poderia adicionar o trecho de código onde você faz a chamada da api?

Comment: Você quer saber se existe uma forma de controlar o comportamento da aplicação cliente que vai consumir a sua WebAPI sem ser você que está programando o lado cliente. É isso?

Comment: Pessoal, muitíssimo obrigado pela ajuda, respondendo ao que o Leandro pediu e ao que o Pagotti perguntou , eu editei a pergunta colocando o trecho do código de exemplo.

Eu tentei chamar o método que consulta assim 
List<Empresa>  ListEmpresa = this.GetAll<Empresa>().Result

Mas aí a consulta a webapi trava e eu não tenho ideia do motivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void btnListaGenerica_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    List<Empresa> list = Task.Run(() => GetAll<Empresa>("empresas/listall")).Result;

    dgvDados.DataSource = list;

}

public List<T> GetAll<T>(string endereco)
{
    List<T> list = new List<T>();

    try
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var response = client.GetAsync("http://localhost:49783/api/" + endereco).Result)
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var ProdutoJsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T[]>(ProdutoJsonString).ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Não foi possível obter o produto : " + response.StatusCode);
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Eitcha!");
        return null;
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

É possível fazer a chamada de forma sincrona, utilizando a palavra chave async antes da chamada do método conforme exemplificado abaixo:

```
private void btnListaGenerica_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Empresa> ListEmpresa = await this.GetAll<Empresa>(); 

    dgvDados.DataSource = ListEmpresa; 
}
```

Mias muito cuidado, deve-se avaliar também se a chamada síncrona não irá bloquear a sua Thread principal causando uma impressão de travamento da tela.

Para maiores esclarecimentos sobre o uso de async e await, veja [este link](http://imasters.com.br/linguagens/c-sharp/c-programacao-assincrona-async-e-await/?trace=1519021197&source=single).

Comment: Oi Julio, muito pela resposta, no caso tomo meu problema era fazer com que minha aplicação travesse mesmo a tela, intencionalmente e eu não conseguia fazer isso.

Bom, eu finalmente consegui. Aqui está o que eu fiz